# How can I get all the Bitcoin transactions data since its inception?

Tags: transactions

If I want to get all the Bitcoin transactions since it started, how do I go about doing this? Is it possible to get all that data from bitcoind database?

Answer (score 1):

This is called the [Blockchain](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Block_chain).  You can access it yourself if you use a client like the reference client, [Bitcoin-QT](https://bitcoin.org/en/download).  By reference, I mean that Bitcoin-QT downloads it to your disk... you have to write a program to access past transations, because Bitcoin-QT doesn't allow you to search past transactions other than your own.

Another way to access the blockchain is to use a web site like [Blockchain.info](http://blockchain.info/). You can either use the web pages to review the blockchain, or use some of their [APIs](http://blockchain.info/api).